# Javascript - replace HTML code

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace some codes in JavaScript. Somehow, this doesn't work.

```
var name = "check & ' &#92;&quot;";
alert(name);
alert(name.replace(/[&quot;]/g, "\""));
alert(name.replace(/[&#92;]/g, "\"));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Those "codes" are called _entities_, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regex, `[]` means "any of the following characters".  So, `/[&#92;]/g` will match a `&`, a `#`, a `9`, a `2` or a `;`.

Try it without the `[]`.

```
var name = "check & ' &#92;&quot;";
alert(name);
alert(name.replace(/&quot;/g, "\""));
alert(name.replace(/&#92;/g, "\""));
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use regex, just parse it:

```
 var d = document.createElement('div');
 d.innerHTML = "check & ' &#92;&quot;";
 console.log(d.innerText);//all done
```

Create an element (in memory, it won't show), and use the `innerText` property, this'll return the text equivalent (ie converts all html-entities to their respective chars).

[read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

As a side-note: the reason why `/[&quot;]/g` would never work is because you're creating a character class/group: it'll match any 1 character of the group, not the entire string:

```
d.innerHTML.replace(/[&quot;]/g,'@');//"check @amp@ ' \""
d.innerHTML.replace(/(&quot;)/g,'@');//"check &amp; ' \""
```

Comment: @DavidThomas: NP, you were right. I had no reason to be blunt

Comment: Meh, we've all been there... =)